# Calling a module's methods on a Gem's object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, koala

I've generated an object via a ruby gem (Koala) and I've written a few modules with helper methods. What do I need to do in order to be able to use the methods within the modules on the object?

If I, model_object = Model.new, model_object will have access to all the instance variables but object does not (see below).

Ruby 2.1, Rails 4.1

config/application.rb - Autoloading modules in folder

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib/module_folder')
```

Model

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   include Module
   include Module::Module2
   include Module::Module3

   def self.create_account(token)
      object = Module.module_class_method(token) #this works and generates the Koala object
      ERROR: object.module2_instance_method # Error: NoMethodError Exception: undefined method
   end
 end
```

Module

```
module Module
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern
end
```

Module2

```
module Module
    module Module2
        def module2_instance_method
        end
    end
end
```

SOLVED MYSELF
- the issue was the include statements being within the class, if I moved them outside it worked.

Comment: show us what you've tried so we can help (i.e. show us code).

Comment: sorry about that, added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the include statements from inside to above the class declaration and all methods began to work. My assumption is that when they are within the statement they are only available to objects of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you include your modules somewhere under the app/ directory - they will be included automatically. Otherwise, you actually have to require them in your rails code explicitly with a require statement

Comment: I've required and included them within the model where they are called but I'm get the error: NoMethodError Exception: undefined method

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual code, I think the problem with `Module2` in your code snippet is the `self.` method.

Because you are calling `module2_instance_method` on an instance of your `object`, the method in the module cannot have the `self.` because that designates a class method and, as such, would have to be called as `Module::Module2.module2_instance_but_not_really_because_I_am_a_class_method`.

I believe if you change `def self.module2_instance_method ... end` to  `def module2_instance_method ... end`, you should no longer receive the `NoMethodError` exception.

Apologies if I've misread or misunderstand the OP.